# The specified procedure could not be found - how to identify?

Tags: windows-7, process, dll, libraries, runtime-error

I'm developing plugins for a program. Whenever I try to load my plugin in that program it crashes with an `the specified procedure could not be found`but nothing more.

Well to have an insight I tracked with `Process Monitor` (or ProcMon). I set the filter to just print messages for the process of my main program. However that application shows me including the libraries ends (after wandering through PATH) at the right file - i.e. Result: SUCCESS.

So my computer left me pretty clueless, yet refuses to work. Has anyone an idea how identify the missing procedure?

**N.B.:**  Additionally I ran the `DependencyWalker` which gave me the usual error message because it's deprecated (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25863297/dependency-walker-gives-me-errors-on-the-system-that-runs-correctly) - which *could* indicate that all dependencies are found.

Comment: How about using a debugger?

Comment: Also, please note that [questions about programming and software development are explicitly off-topic on Super User](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Such questions can however be asked on [so], but you will *have* to show prior effort there or your questions will be downvoted to oblivion.